# How to decide on size of state space?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I'm in a reinforcement learning class and we're working on a dice game problem where you profit the number rolled for certain digits and lose all your money on certain other digits.  You can choose to roll or quit and take your current winnings at any step.

The main question that I'm struggling with is how big exactly to make my state space.  I've set it to represent the profit ($0, $1, $2, $3, et cetera).  However, I don't exactly understand how to size my state space.  N = 100, N = 1000?  N= 30?  We haven't gotten much guidance on the question and it's gotten me hamstrung.

Another thing I'm stumped on is how exactly I'm generating my transition matrix.  Let's say that 4 out of 6 digits on the dice result in a reward, and the other 2 result in me losing all my winnings back down to zero.  Am I incorrect in assuming that the probability of increasing my bankroll in any state is 66.6667%, and 33.3334% for losing it all?  If I have a state space of N = 100, my probability matrix is 100 x 100?  I'm incredibly confused about transitions.  I'm also lost about how to factor in rolling or quitting into the equation once I'm actually iterating over values.

Comment: you cannot assume we know what's the setting/problem with as explanation _"you profit the number rolled for certain digits and lose all your money on certain other digits"_, please provide an actual accurate explanation of the problem